# In SQL, adding a set of values corresponding on a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, insert

Let's say that I have **Table_A** contain:

```
ID OldValue
3     16
1     5
```

and **Table_B** contains

```
ID Value OldValue
1    2     NULL
2    4     NULL 
3    8     NULL
```

and that I want to insert OldValues from Table_A into Table_B where the IDs equal resulting in :

**updated Table_B**

```
ID Value OldValue
1    2     5
2    4     NULL 
3    8     16
```

Is there a set based way of doing this without using a cursor? In real life this will be going on very large tables and cursors, as we all know are slow. Perhaps some sort of Merge?

I'm on SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update Table_B
Set OldValue = A.OldValue
From Table_A As A
    Join Table_B As B
        On B.ID = A.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You want an "update from"

```
UPDATE B
SET B.OldValue = A.OldValue
FROM Table_B B
INNER JOIN Table_A  ON B.ID = A.ID
```

Generally I write this as a select, then once i get the result I convert it over to the update.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
update x set OldValue = a.OldValue
from Table_B x
join Table_A a on x.ID = a.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
UPDATE TABLE_B
SET OLDAVLUE=A.OLDVALUE
FROM TABLE_B B 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A A ON B.ID=A.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps some sort of Merge?

Indeed. The following is Standard SQL that is supported on SQL Server 2008:

```
MERGE INTO Table_B
   USING Table_A
      ON Table_B.ID = Table_A.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET OldValue = Table_A.OldValue;
```